# Partial vs function literal when memoize

Tags: clojure, memoization

This is giving me a bit of brain thump:

```
user> (repeatedly 10 #((memoize rand-int) 10))
(7 0 4 8 1 2 2 1 6 9)
user> (repeatedly 10 (partial (memoize rand-int) 10))
(8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8)
```

I would like to know if the reason for this is because the function literal (first version) is called/evaluated every time, thus the `memoize` is "recreated" (re-memorized) each time, therefore not really having any true meaningful "memorization" at all, while the second one with `partial` is actually returning a fixed function that is evaluated just once, where the same value of `memoize` is thus used every time (sort of like a closure though I don't think this qualifies as a true "closure")

Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: OpenLearner: the question is Clojure specific. The specific functions and the syntax are not defined in other Lisp dialects. You don't need to tag any specific question with the more general tag. Please use the Lisp tag for questions which are related to general Lisp questions or questions which are relevant for users of different Lisp dialects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `memoize` doesn't modify its argument in any way, so

```
#((memoize rand-int) 10)
```

recreates the memoized function on each call.

```
(fn [] ((memoize rand-int) 10))
```

is equivalent.

To call a memoized function from another function, you need to put it in a Var or a closed-over local:

```
(repeatedly 10 (let [r (memoize rand-int)] #(r 10)))
;= (2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2)
```

In the `partial` example, the function returned by `(memoize rand-int)` is passed as an argument to the function `partial`, which then returns a closure which closes over the return of `(memoize rand-int)`. So, this is very close to the example above (except the closure returned by `partial` uses `apply` to call the memoized function).