# Clojure partial right

Tags: clojure

I have the following function

```
(defn fun [a b] (str a b))

(fun "1" "2") ;; --> "12"
```

Thanks to `(partial)` I can turn it into `(fun b)` and have a fixed `a`

```
(def fun2 (partial fun "1"))

(fun2 "2") ;; --> "12"
```

Does clojure have something like `(partial-right)` or a way to rearrange the arguments of a function so that instead of having a fixed `a` I can have a fixed `b` and hence have the function `(fun a)`?

Thanks

Comment: since it was recently asked in irc, no.  option: `#(fun % "2")`

Comment: @cfrick Note that this is not equivalent to `partial` (or some related construct) if `fun` is impure; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931512/partial-vs-function-literal-when-memoize).

Comment: "fun"?  i,e. `fn`, @cfrick?

Comment: @Mars No, the `fun` defined at the beginning of the original question.

Comment: Ah, right, @Elogent.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defn partial-right [f & args1]
    (fn [& args2]
        (apply f (concat args2 args1))))
```

But ask yourself...why isn't this already part of the standard library? Is it perhaps that other people have wandered this way and it turned out badly?

Comment: I don't know.  What''s your opinion?

Comment: @NeilMasson Well, I was in this exact position which is why I have a code answer to this question but I was challenged by a senior Clojurian and given this advice. It could be considered non-idiomatic (otherwise it'd be an obvious addition to the stdlib)

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example you could go with multi arity:

```
(defn fun 
  ([a b] (str a b))
  ([a] (str a "1")))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, just provides a solution to the author's immediate example.